# How can I force this font to render in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

## UPDATE

This is only happening in IE on Windows 7 machines.  IE has no problem with the font on machines running Windows 8.1.  I don't have a machine running Windows 8, so I can't verify that version.

## UPDATE 2

I called around to a few friends and the font is fine on their Windows 7 machines, so I am lost here.  The only other thing I can think to do is look for Windows updates that I may have missed. . .

## UPDATE 3

I have installed all Windows updates, including the optional ones.  IE11 is also up to date.  Still, the fonts don't render in IE on my Win 7 machine.  Even though, it works fine on other Win 7 machines I have tested, I am leaving this post up because I would really like to get to the bottom of this.

## Original Post

I have had a look at several related stack questions, but have not yet found a solution.  I am only posting this in case what I am experiencing is some edge case that hasn't been covered in related questions:

I am attempting to use this font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'duaselight';
    src: url('../fonts/duase_light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/duase_light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/duase_light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/duase_light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/duase_light-webfont.svg#duaselight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The font files and CSS were generated using [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) and they work fine in every other browser except for IE (of course).

The font itself can be [downloaded for free here](http://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=duase).

Here is my implementation:

```
#bottom-section h2 {
    font-family: "duaselight";
    font-size: 2.2em;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

I have tried:

- Adding a full URL to the `@font-face`
- Reordering the `src` properties in `@font-face`

I have also verified the fonts are indeed being downloaded by IE, just not rendered.

Hopefully someone can spot an obvious oversight.  Thanks.

Comment: `duase_light-webfont.eot?#iefix'` does seem to have the same url folder structure as the others? Path issue?

Comment: @Paulie_D: Are you saying that the `.eot` file should be renamed for the `iefix`?  Thanks!

Comment: No...I'm saying that all the other font formats have `../fonts/` in the url and that one doesn't. Just a thought.

Comment: @Paulie_D--Ok, I see, you are correct, but that was just from transcribing over to this post.  I will fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you show us a link to somewhere that we can see this problem?

Comment: @Adam, sure: www.polyrific.com, BUT I have an important update I just discovered.  This only is a problem on Windows 7 Machines!!  Win 8 & 8.1 is fine.

Comment: How does the problem manifest itself? Exactly what does not look right, in which way?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela--The correct font does not render.  Only the web-safe fall back font renders (Arial).